# Nutch 2, add new field in plugin

Tags: nutch

i try to write plugin for nutch 2, but can't find any info in internet how to add new field in plugin. No information about plugins for nutch 2.

In nutch 1.x "WebPage" just have method "add"

Comment: Under src/gora there is a webpage.asvc. Add the field here and rebuild nutch. That should add the field to the compiled Webpage.class.